# Get value from another component

Tags: angular, ionic3

So I have to component, one that have an update from the username

> Set.ts

```
 updateSurname() {
 inputs: [
    {
      name: 'surname',
    },
  ],
    {
      handler: data => {
        console.log(data.surname)
      }
    }
  ]
}).present();
```

}

When i do console.log(data.surname),i get the surname i want to get it on the other component

> Whereiwanttoreadthevalue.ts

```
import { Set } from '../../pages/settings/set';
export class MessageModal {

  surname =this.data.surname;

....}
```

Comment: Not clear @Taieb your question ?this.pickRandomPunchline('SURNAME') what is the function?  i want to get it on the other component mean

Comment: @Utpaul I have a Setting page where i can change my username.

in the second page Where i wat to acesse the value, i want to call data.surname. that i edited in my setting.ts

Comment: i solve your problem please check it??

Comment: response me as soon as possible ... i solve your problem.. please check it...

Answer (score 0):

This is a very strange syntax (I recommend using typescript) but if I get you right: what you need is a service, which you can inject into both components via their constructor:

`constructor(_valueService: ValueService)`

and then in _valueService you define the variable as public. 
`public myValue: any`

after this, you can set, get, etc. that like this: `this._valueService.myValue = ...`

Comment: Sorry, yeah it's in typescript, i did a mistake on the spelling